# java same function with different main action

Tags: java

Hey so my situation is like this - I have 2 functions who are exactly the same but with the main action in them is different :

```
public static void Set(String key, String value) {
    ObjectNode config = GetConfig();
    config.put(key,value);
    WriteConfig(config);
}

public static void Delete(String key) {
    ObjectNode config = GetConfig();
    config.delete(key);
    WriteConfig(config);
}
```

Now I was interesed if there is some way I can make this code pretty and only have to write the surronding code once and sending the main action somehow.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Doesn't look like Java. But I don't see anything wrong with the approach itself, I would leave it as it is.

Comment: Here I changed it to what it really is.

Comment: How is this *not* Java? @kocko

Comment: @DonLarynx check the previous status before the edit.

Comment: @DonLarynx look at the edits ;)

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski I guess it is ok when I have 2 functions. but lets say I have 4? or 10 for that matter? I just feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you are after if you are using Java 8. First, you create a general `command` function:

```
public static void command(Consumer<ObjectNode> function) {
    ObjectNode config = getConfig();
    function.accept(config);
    writeConfig(config);
}
```

Then you can let your other methods use the general `command`, specifying the middle main action as an argument:

```
public static void set(String key, String value) {
    command(config -> config.put(key, value));
}

public static void delete(String key) {
    command(config -> config.delete(key));
}
```